# How do you add contacts to iCloud on iPhone?

Tags: icloud

I can't seem to figure out why some of my contacts are linked to iCloud and some aren't. I want to create groups but can't because the contacts are not linked.

Comment: Do you have a Mac? Is your AppleID signed in on both the Mac and the iPhone? Is Contacts ticked to synch via iCloud in System Preferences on the Mac and in Settings on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple “containers” to store contacts.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207207

If you turn off iCloud is will be easy to determine which are locally stored on the device and which are from another service. Once you know that, you can plan to merge or clean them up.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203565